# Ubuntu 12.04 - Timemachine - Suddenly can't find disk

Tags: macbook-pro, time-machine, osx-mountain-lion, ubuntu-12.04, netatalk

I have used my Ubuntu server as backup through my network with my Mac Book Pro Mountain Lion for a while. But suddenly it won't work. It sais it can't find the disk. Even though I can connect through

"connect to server" afp://192.168.1.121 and mount the disc to my mac book pro and see the sparsebundle.

I have tried to reconfigure my afpd and netatalk settings but with no success it still gives me the same error.

This is my conf:

```
AFPD.conf
- -tcp -noddp -uamlist uams_randnum.so,uams_dhx.so,uams_dhx2.so -nosavepassword

netatalk.conf

ATALK_NAME=`echo ${HOSTNAME}|cut -d. -f1`
ATALK_UNIX_CHARSET=’LOCALE’
ATALK_MAC_CHARSET=’MAC_ROMAN’
export ATALK_UNIX_CHARSET
export ATALK_MAC_CHARSET
CNID_METAD_RUN=yes
AFPD_RUN=yes
AFPD_MAX_CLIENTS=20
ATALKD_RUN=no
PAPD_RUN=no
TIMELORD_RUN=no
A2BOOT_RUN=no
```

Have I missed something?